# Can I travel to Canada on a visitor visa if I have been deported from the United States?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, canada, deportation, air-india

I was recently deported from the USA. My status was as F1 student Visa I was studying well but was doing a job. At the time of immigration, they found that I was working and gave me justification of deportation for 5 years. I requested them to complete my study as it was only 6 months left. I also have a Canada visitor Visa for 10 years. Now my question is that can I travel to Canada with my passport.

Comment: Canada and the US (and Australia, New Zealand, and the U.K.) share biometric data. I think it’s likely you’d be denied entry.

Answer (score 2):

This information came from my wife who is an immigration consultant working in Ontario Canada

A person can say he was deported when he actually just received a removal notice (usually it says you have violated Rules XXX and you no longer have a legal temporary status in the USA. You are required to leave USA on this day.) but a formal deportation order is a different thing. usually you get it when you are arrested and detained for a period of time. You will not be released until you are removed directly.

If you leave voluntarily, your Canadian visa might still work, but if you have been issued a deportation order, you most likely won't be able to enter Canada.